# Hibernate, SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance with abstract class in the middle of the hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Consider the following entity hierarchy tree:

```
-  Parameter (abstract)
-- ConstantParameter
-- GenerableParameter (abstract)
--- AnalogParameter
--- DigitalParameter
```

On the db side, there is a `parameters` table with a discriminator column `category` that can take the following values `constant`, `analog` or `digital`.

Parameter abstract root entity and leaf entities can easily be mapped using SINGLE_TABLE inheritance and using `category` column as discriminator column.

Now, an abstract entity `GenerableParameter` has been added on the tree between Parameter and (AnalogParameter & DigitalParameter) to denote a specific behaviour which applies only to theses two leaf entities.

How can i map this intermediary abstract entity `GenerableParameter` in order to be able to query on it (in my case it means create a Repository using Spring data jpa) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i answer myself because i have found the solution.

In fact it works out of the box (have not tested before ask the question because i wanted some lightning about implementation).

The GenerableParameter abstract entity only needs `@Entity`. I am able to query on it. The results are as expected: ConstantParameter records are discarded.